# Tomcat IIS integration on Windows Server 2012

Tags: tomcat, iis, windows-server-2012-r2, isapi

I am trying to integrate IIS with Tomcat9 so IIS will be a web server and Tomcat will process servlets.

I followed an instructions outlined at : https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/iis.html

I downloaded ISAPI connector and installed under the Tomcat deployment. At some point I had to execute this instruction :

In IIS Management console execute the following:

***Select the newly created virtual directory in the management console and then double-click Handler Mappings. Select the (currently disabled) ISAPI-dll entry and then click Edit Feature Permissions in the action pane. In the dialog box that opens, select Execute so all three permissions are selected. Click OK and ISAPI-dll should now be in the enabled state.***

and when I clicked on "Handler Mappings" icon in the resulting window I didn't find "ISAPI-dll" entry. After quick investigation I found out that I had to install "ISAPI Extensions" and "ISAPI Filters" features of IIS. I went to the "Control Panel" and clicked on  "Turn on and off Windows features". I was redirected to the "Server Manager" application and those features were absent.

I tried the same procedure on my Windows 10 machine and I was able to see and install these features.

Is it a problem with Windows Server 2012 or there is some other way to install IIS features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great question, with an easy answer. The IIS features probably live in .net xxx or asp.net xxx. Here are some instructions that will help you find them. Enjoy

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav/how-to--install-and-configure-internet-information-services-for-microsoft-dynamics-nav-web-client

Comment: jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (815): connect to 127.0.0.1:8009 failed (errno=61)
[Wed Jun 02 15:13:25.773 2021] [3868:4872] [info] ajp_connect_to_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (1064): (tomcat01) Failed opening socket to (127.0.0.1:8009) (errno=61)

Comment: Hmm... Can you post your server.xml file? Thanks!

Comment: <Connector protocol="AJP/1.3"
               address="::"
               port="8009"
      secretRequired="true"
      secret="xxxxx"
               redirectPort="8443" />

Comment: Success! Change 
***
address ="::"
***
 to
***
address ="127.0.0.1"
***